# Is it possible to convert a column contain numeric and character into numeric in R arrow?

Tags: r, character, numeric, apache-arrow

For example,
if I run the following code:

```
library(arrow)
library(tidyverse)

mtcars$cyl[2:5] = 'a'

mtcars %>%
  arrow_table() %>%
  mutate(cyl = cast(cyl, numeric())) %>% 
  collect()
```

An error message popped up:

```
Error in `compute.arrow_dplyr_query()`:
! Invalid: Failed to parse string: 'a' as a scalar of type double
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I expect the result would be error-free and those 'a' will be converted into `NA`. However, it seems that the property of `cast` function is not the same as `as.numeric` in r.

Comment: The cast function is more strict in type casting and expects values that can be directly converted to the target type. You can check documentation here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arrow/arrow.pdf. You can add if else to check if data is numeric before cast to that specific data type

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand that it is stricter than `as.numeric`. So I am wondering whether `cast` will have the property that is similar to `as.numeric`, which can convert non-numeric to `NA` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

seems to work

```
library(arrow)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

mtcars$cyl[2:5] = 'a'

mtcars %>%
  arrow_table() %>%
  mutate(
         cyl = cast(if_else(str_detect(cyl, "^[0-9]+$"),
                               cyl,NA_character_), numeric())) %>% 
  collect()
```